# How delayed can IFTTT triggers be?

Tags: ifttt

I've been using IFTTT for various tasks, and it works relatively well, but for the triggers I've been using (RSS feed updates) the update time is quite slow (up to 15 minutes of delay after the feed is updated. For high-frequency feeds, 15 minutes is a severe delay, but in my use case this is manageable, so I'm not too concerned.

For other triggers and recipes I want to create, I need to be able to respond more quickly to an event. For example, if I receive an email, I'd like IFTTT to perform an action much more quickly (within 5 minutes at most).

Ignoring any issues with IFTTT being down, how can I determine how quickly a trigger will fire? Is the time to react based on the applet (I assume some applets might have push triggers, so IFTTT will be able to respond more quickly)?

Comment: normally IFTTT doesn't take that long for a response. maybe a delay upto a minute. 15 minutes seem to be a long wait!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

15 minutes after ringing my Ring doorbell (notifications from the Ring app come literally instantly) my lights (also instant from the app) blink.

20 seconds after pressing a Amazon AWS Dash button, the function is executed.

Point is: The delay can be anywhere from 5 seconds, to 50 minutes. Do **not** rely on IFTTT.

Comment: I have experienced multiple hour delays for certain actions, notably creation of files in dropbox.